# Cauchy sequence in the Euclidean and Infinity metric

Tags: calculus

Show that a sequence of points in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Cauchy in the usual Euclidean metric if and only if it is Cauchy in the $1$ (or infinity) metric.

Comment: This due to equivalence of norms in finite dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that  $\|x\|_1$ and $\|x\|_\infty$ are small if $\|x\|_2$ is small.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that the norms are equivalent in finite dimensional spaces, that is

> $$ C_1\,||x||_1 \leq ||x||_{\infty} \leq C_2 \,||x||_1 . $$

Here is a [reference](http://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf).